# Can't shoot while moving in specific degrees (or rotations values) JAVA LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the following problem: I am practicing in JAVA using LibGdx libraries. I am making a little  2D spacecraft shooting game... I can move my sprite nice, and shoot perfect (like I want) while I am not moving the sprite, but the problem start when I move the sprite and try to shoot.

[image]

I'll let the code next to a picture to illustrate how I'm doing the path of the shot... this is the Laser function where I define the path of the shot, in some quarters, the spacecraft is not shooting while moving, and I cant find the reason:

```
public Laser shoot(float grados, float x, float y){
    Laser obj = new Laser();        
    if(grados == 0){ //Ok
        obj.setVelocidadX(500);
        obj.setVelocidadY(0);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 80, y + 45);
    }
    if (grados == 90){ //Ok
        obj.setVelocidadX(0);
        obj.setVelocidadY(500);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 55, y + 80);
    }
    if (grados == 180){ //Ok
        obj.setVelocidadX(-500);
        obj.setVelocidadY(0);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 10, y + 55);
    }
    if(grados == -90){ //Ok
        obj.setVelocidadX(0);
        obj.setVelocidadY(-500);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 45,y + 10);
    }
    if(grados > 0 && grados < 90){ //OK
        obj.setVelocidadX(500);
        obj.setVelocidadY(500);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 75, y + 70);   
    }
    if(grados > 90 && grados < 180){ //The spaceship not shoot
        obj.setVelocidadX(-500);
        obj.setVelocidadY(500);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 25 , y + 80);
    }
    if(grados > -180 && grados < -90){ //The spaceship not shoot
        obj.setVelocidadX(-500);
        obj.setVelocidadY(-500);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 20, y + 25);
    }
    if(grados > -90 && grados < 0){ //The spaceship not shoot
        obj.setVelocidadX(500);
        obj.setVelocidadY(-500);
        obj.setRotacion(grados);
        obj.setPosition(x + 75, y + 15);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

[image]

Render code for move the spacecraft:

```
    float dt = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    fireDelay -= dt;
    nave.velocidadX = 0;
    nave.velocidadY = 0;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
        if(fireDelay <= 0){
        escenario.addActor(nave.shoot(nave.getRotation(),nave.getX(),nave.getY()));
        fireDelay = 0.3f;
        }
    }
    if(nave.velocidadX == 0 && nave.velocidadY == 0){nave.setAnimation(detenido);}
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
        nave.velocidadX -= 200;
        nave.setAnimation(corriendo);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
        nave.velocidadX += 200;
        nave.setAnimation(corriendo);            
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)){
        nave.velocidadY += 200;
        nave.setAnimation(corriendo);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)){
        nave.velocidadY -= 200;
        nave.setAnimation(corriendo);
    }
```

I would like the ship to fire in all directions while moving...

UPDATE: I discovered a new problem, I can´t hold down three keys at once in quadrants shown in red . I can only in the first quadrant ( 0 to 90 ).

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Can you provide any additional information that may help diagnose the issue?

Comment: @AustinD It is all that I have to show in terms of the mobility of the ship and shooting ... I do not understand why not shoot while moving in certain quadrants of the plane (which I noted in the drawing that I uploaded) ... I can show what follows the render code (things that do not have nothing to do with mobility or shooting)

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. It turns out that my code was right ... The problem? ... It was my keyboard. It seems that my keyboard does not support simultaneously holding down certain key combinations ... I had to enter the next page to test which combinations worked:

https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/keyboardghostingdemo.mspx